# Python: How to debug high CPU consumption on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, docker, performance, debugging

I have a Python application that I am developing on Windows. I need to investigate a complaint that my app consumes 100% CPU when running in Linux.

I was able to reproduce the issue by:

1. Running a Docker container based on Debian (`python:3.9.13-buster`).
2. Cloning my git repo into the container.
3. Building my app (`poetry` ftw) and running it.
4. Running `top` to see that a `python` process is indeed consuming 100% CPU (and oddly enough occasionally more).

**How do I debug my app in the container to understand which part of my code is misbehaving?** Is there a utility that can profile my python program as it's running to pinpoint the offending code?

PS - I've tried using `gdb -p <thread_id>` and its `bt` command but I can't make sense of the stack trace printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question in the hope others might find it useful in the future.

I've been able to use [`py-spy`](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy)'s `top` command on my program as it was running inside the container and its output has showed me that the `hupper` library is the cause of the high CPU usage.

Here are the steps that I've taken:

1. I had to spin up a new container with the `SYS_PTRACE` capability otherwise [`py-spy` can't run inside it](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-run-py-spy-in-docker):

   ```
   docker run -it --cap-add SYS_PTRACE python:3.9.13-buster /bin/bash
   ```
2. I cloned my app into the container, built it, and ran it.
3. I ran `top` to see what the process id is for my program (identifiable by its high CPU usage).
4. I ran `py-spy top --pid <process id>` to see a live table showing me the most active parts of my code.

Similar to this:

```
(python v3.9.13)
Total Samples 78500
GIL: 15.00%, Active: 103.00%, Threads: 4

  %Own   %Total  OwnTime  TotalTime  Function (filename)
 92.00%  92.00%   717.0s    717.0s   get_mtime (hupper/polling.py)
  3.00%   3.00%   41.27s    67.08s   walk (dash/_watch.py)
  7.00%  99.00%   35.86s    752.9s   check_reload (hupper/polling.py)
  1.00% 100.00%   20.21s    773.1s   run (hupper/polling.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   17.08s    18.78s   _walk (os.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    4.24s     4.24s   <listcomp> (dash/_watch.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    2.49s     2.89s   join (posixpath.py)
  0.00%   0.00%    1.60s     1.60s   islink (posixpath.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.400s    0.400s   _get_sep (posixpath.py)
  0.00%   3.00%   0.210s    67.29s   watch (dash/_watch.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.030s    0.030s   _run_worker (hupper/reloader.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.020s    0.020s   _recv_packet (hupper/ipc.py)
  0.00%   3.00%   0.000s    67.31s   run (threading.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.000s    0.030s   start_reloader (hupper/reloader.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.000s    0.030s   <module> (<string>)
  0.00%   3.00%   0.000s    67.29s   <lambda> (dash/dash.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.000s    0.030s   serve (myapp/cli/main.py)
  0.00% 103.00%   0.000s    840.4s   _bootstrap (threading.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.000s    0.030s   serve_dashboard (myapp/dashboard/__init__.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.000s    0.030s   wrapper (myapp/cli/main.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.000s    0.020s   _read_loop (hupper/ipc.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.000s    0.030s   main (myapp/cli/main.py)
  0.00%   0.00%   0.000s    0.030s   run (hupper/reloader.py)
```